# sqsh gives "dsp_desc_bind: Memory allocation failure for column #1"

Tags: freetds, sqsh

On Ubuntu 18.04 with freetds 1.00.82-2 and sqsh 2.1.7-4build1, I get the following when trying to `SELECT foo FROM bar` where `foo` is an nvarchar column:

`dsp_desc_bind: Memory allocation failure for column #1`

Why does this happen? I see some ancient [bug](https://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2009q1/024256.html) [reports](http://freetds.ibiblio.narkive.com/MDnbqw9n/tds7-0-sqsh-and-text-columns-in-cvs), but I can't see any solutions there; this error message is quite ungooglable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried downgrading freetds to 0.91.6, which I had working on Ubuntu 17.10, and then got the more understandable error message

`Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.`

which led me to the solution:

Edit `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` and add a section

```
[YourDbHostname]
      host = localhost
      port = 1433
      tds version = 8.0
```

Now it works :)

EDIT: Seems like sqsh-2.5.16.1 ignores this file now? Another solution is to just use the `-G` argument, e.g. `sqsh -G 8.0 -i foo.sql`